\colorstretch from chickenize does not work anymore
The  chickenize packages most useful function, the \colorstretch does not work anymore:
% !TeX program = lualatex 
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{chickenize} 
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\colorstretch
\blindtext

\end{document}

gives an error, which is not at all helpful:
warning  (node filter): error: /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/chickenize/chic
kenize.lua:995: attempt to index a nil value (global 'n')

.
<argument> ...ype:D \tex_hskip:D \c_zero_dim \fi: \tex_par:D 
                                                  \hook_use:n {para/after}\@...

I use TexLive 2024.2-3 on Manjaro Linux (chickenize v0.3) and i dont know when the last time was, that the  \colorstretch worked. I'm grateful for all help.

If I modify line 995 I get

which seems (using Overleaf) to match what was made in earlier releases.
I saved chikenize.lua to the current directory and changed line 995 from
texio.write_nl(n.id)

to
if n and n.id then texio.write_nl(n.id) end

so it skips  that line if n is nil so avoiding the error, but I didn't trace what has changed to make n nil in current releases.

I wonder if it is the para hook.

@UlrikeFischer I suspect so, but the lua callback ought to be seeing just the node lists after all such things have been expanded out, but I'm not sure and didn't feel like tracing it:-)
